# Can you import user-defined scala classes into proto?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

I have been tasked to create a general case class that would cover different kinds of config (existing already in the system).

Here's a sample of the configs:

```
package ngage.sdk.configs
...
object Config {

  case class TokenConfig(expiry: FiniteDuration)

  case class SagaConfig(timeOut: FiniteDuration, watcherTimeout: FiniteDuration)

  case class ElasticConfig(connectionString: String, deletePerPage: Int)

  case class S3Config(bucket: String)

  case class RedisConfig(host: String, port: Int)
...
```

I looked to protobuf for a solution, but I don't know how to import the case classes as mentioned above.

Here's how I started:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package ngage.sdk.distributedmemory.config;

import "scalapb/scalapb.proto";
import "pboptions.proto";
import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
import "ngage.sdk.configs.Config"; //this became red

option (scalapb.options) = {
  flat_package: true
  single_file: true
};

message ShardMemoryConfig {
    option (ngage.type_id) = 791;

    int32 size = 1;

    oneof config { //everything inside oneof is red
        ngage.sdk.configs.RedisConfig redis = 100002;

        ngage.sdk.configs.ElasticConfig elastic = 100003;

        ngage.sdk.configs.S3Config s3 = 100004;
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to import user-defined scala classes to protobuf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a library which generates `.proto` files from case class definitions, I don't know if one exists (but I would expect not). [PBDirect](https://github.com/btlines/pbdirect) lets you write/read case classes directly, but then your `ShardMemoryConfig` should also be a case class using `RedisConfig` etc.

Comment: Well, that is not appealing. case class -> generate proto -> generate case class

It looks like protobuf is not the solution after all.
I'll just have to set `ShardMemoryConfig` as a sealed trait, and update those case classes to extend on it.

Thanks Alexey!